# How to call VB.net DLLs from C++ using COM

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll, com

I was recently assigned to write some code in C++ that calls DLLs that were written in VB.net.  The VB.net DLLs are actually written by another group within my company.  Because of turf wars within the company, they won't let me see their code, but they are responsive when I ask questions.  The team writing the VB.net code is on the other side of the planet, and every question I ask them takes a one day turn around.  Interesting position to be in, but the politics seem insurmountable.

All of the work, on the VB.net and C++ code, has been done using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.  I have registered the DLLs using regasm.  I can see the GUIDs of all of the classes and interfaces.  I have used oleview to look at the contents of the generated type library files, and verified that these items show up in the registry on my machine.

The VB.net DLLs have been demonstrated to work, when they are executed from within a VB.net framework, where they can all be referenced and shared between, but I don't believe there has been any effort invested in testing these DLLs using the COM interface.

This is my first foray into COM.  From the reading I have been doing it looks like COM is relatively old technology, but it is the only avenue I have found so far, that allows me to mix languages.  If someone has a better suggestion, I'm all ears.  I'd still like to chase this one down, because I feel like I'm really close.

I have managed to call methods in these DLLs, using CoInitialize, and CoCreateinstance. Early on, I found that some of the classes were marked as noncreateable, or the interfaces were not public.  I told the VB.net developers.  They made some changes, and sent me another set of DLLs, and I was able to access interfaces that were previously not exposed.

I am at the point where I call these VB.net DLLs, and the code returns successfully, but without appearing to have any effect on the hardware I am trying to initialize.  I know that these VB.net DLLs have dependencies on other VB.net DLLs that go several layers deep.  My suspicion is that I am managing to call the top level DLL, but as soon as it calls into another DLL I'm not sure what happens, and I have no visibility.  I'm relatively certain that the call to the other DLL is not COM aware.

I'm looking for some suggestions on how to debug this, or dig deeper.  At one point, I was getting errors when any other these other DLLs were called, that said:

```
"Driver class 'foo' could not be created.  Ensure class name and DLL version are    correct."
```

This error popped up for all of the VB.net DLLs that called between each other.  I copied all of the DLLs to the same location as the executable, and these errors went away.

I have done some research that suggests stack state needs to be carefully managed, in such scenarios, but I'm not sure what needs to go in the VB code, if anything.

Do the VB.net DLLs need to do anything to handle this?  When I am calling VB.net DLLs from C++, can the VB.net DLLs hopscotch between each other, under the hood, or does this entire solution need to be rearchitected?  What kinds of requests can I send the VB.net developers
that would allow me to call top level routines from C++, that would in turn allow the VB.net DLLs to call between each other?

Coincidentally, there was a previous project, very similar in nature, where this all worked, with one significant difference - all of the VB.net code was contained within a single DLL.  I think my issue may be related to the fact that the VB.net DLLs are not able to call between each other, but I have not been able to find any websites that answered this particular question.  Is this allowed?  Do the VB.net DLLs need to be modified to allow calls to other DLLs when the top level call is coming through COM?

Comment: In spite of all apparent wealth of info, it's unclear what you're basically asking. But it's relatively simple, I think. Do these DLLs expose COM classes? If so use COM. Do they expose .NET classes? If so use .NET.

Comment: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Sorry, if I didn't manage to express my question clearly. Phillip's response captured the essence of what I was trying to ask. The DLLs I'm calling were written in VB.net, AFAIK, but they are being accessed using CoInitialize and CoCreateInstance, which are COM. Does this mean I'm mixing things, and using COM to access .net DLLs?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend starting by exploring the VB.Net dlls from .Net using VB.Net. You could also use [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) or C# (which isn't a million miles from C++ in terms of syntax).

Once you've worked out the API calls have the expected behaviour then try invoking via COM or via a [mixed (native and managed)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0w2664k.aspx) assembly.

> I copied all of the DLLs to the same location as the executable, and these errors went away.

AFAIK whether there's one .Net DLL or multiple .Net DLLs should make no difference when you're calling via COM as long as they are in the same folder or registered in the [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache).

> stack state needs to be carefully managed

When calling COM objects from C++ you need to be careful when marshalling values, for example see [How to: Marshal COM Strings Using C++ Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b610yw3t.aspx). Depending on how much marshalling you need to do, it can get pretty ugly quite quickly, you might find you're better off using a [.Net language](http://trelford.com/blog/post/FS4C11.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. At least this gives me a little bit more confidence that there should be no issues once I get into the the DLLs.  The DLLs should be able to call between each other, from what you suggest.